# How to find the equation of a graph with given coordinates?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing a function $f$ when $x$ and $f(x)$ are known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108566/writing-a-function-f-when-x-and-fx-are-known)

If I am given 9 co-ordinates of a random graph say for e.g

```
1. (2,1)
2. (4,3)
3. (7,9)
4. (9,5)
5. (10,3)
6. (11,1) 
7. (13,4)
8. (15,7)
9. (17,10)
```

[image: this is the plotted graph exactly however it needs to be curved]

((this is the plotted graph exactly  however it needs to be curved ))

How can i create an equation to approximately fit the graphs trendline curve.

Comment: You should probably say which kind of "equation" or function you want. A priori there are various possibilities to write down a function such that all these points lie on the graph.

Comment: sorry a polynomial equation

Comment: You can use an interpolating polynomial, then...

Answer (score 2):

You want to find a polynomial such that a given number of points lie on the graph. 
observe that every given point is a "condition" on your function. A polynmial of degree $n$ is of the form
$$P(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$$
and has therefore $n+1$ degrees of freedom. So for $n$ given points a polynomial of degree $n-1$ should do the job.
Hence assume $P(x)$ is a solution. Just plug in your given points, one at a time. E.g.
$$P(2)=1$$
$$P(4)=3$$
$$\cdots$$
$$P(17)=10$$

You will obtain $n$ linear equations for your $n$ variables which you now have to solve. As an advanced exercise: what does it mean if the system has multiple solutions?

Comment: Do you mean trial and error? But is there an algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you are trying to fit a straight line to the data?

One common method is least squares, that is, in this case, find $a_0,a_1$ to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^9 (a_0+a_1 x_i - y_i)^2$, where $(x_i, y_i)$ are your data above. If we let
$$D=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 \\ 1 & x_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots\end{bmatrix}, b=
 \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots\end{bmatrix}, a = \begin{bmatrix} a_0  \\ a_1\end{bmatrix},$$
then we can write the problem as $\min_{a \in \mathbb{R}^2} || D a -b ||_2^2.$ The minimizing solution satisfies
$$D^T(Da-b) = 0,$$
so we have $a = (D^T D)^{-1}D^T y$. In your case, this (or rather Octave) gives $a=\binom{1.26406}{0.35936}$. So the line $x \mapsto 1.26406+0.35936 x$ is the best-fit line in a least squares sense.